# How to configure VSCode task to compile multiple files on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, compilation, linker

I have a project to compile in VSCode that consists of multiple source files and want to add a single argument to my task that would tell g++ to link all files with .cpp extension. The following does not work:

```
"args": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp*",
    ...
```

`g++: error: /home/kirusfg/Study/Programming/CSCI 152/Assignments/Assignment 4/*.cpp*: No such file or directory`,

even though

`g++ '/home/kirusfg/Study/Programming/CSCI 152/Assignments/Assignment 4/*.cpp*' -o main-optimized.out -g -O5 -flto -Wreturn-type -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wundef -std=c++17`

works perfectly if entered via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are having issues with space in your 'workspaceFolder' path, "args" field not handling spaces well.

It seems like your best option is to add the arg to the "command" field.

i.e.:

```
... 
"command": "g++ ${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp*",
"args":[],
...
```

I hope it will fix your issue.

Reference:
See closed issue from VScode GitHub: [How to pass arguments with space to tasks correctly](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36733)

Comment: The terminal shell path "/home/kirusfg/Study/Programming/CSCI 152/Assignments/Assignment 4/*.cpp*" does not exist

Comment: Can you post the entire task?